# NancyFX Routing issue

Tags: .net, nancy

I'm having weird routing issue with NancyFX

```
Public class BooModule : NancyModule
{
    public BooModule() : base("/boo")

    {
      Get["/foo"] = x => {...};  
    }
}
```

I use VS2013. If I debug and go to

> http:/localhost/myProject/boo/foo

It goes into BooModule but doesn't invoke Foo method. I get empty response.
I tried playing with slashes but that didn't help. Any ideas what's going on here?
Thanks!

Comment: Never mind 401 Unauthorized IP address

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to remove myProject from the URI.

Did you add Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet to the project?

If you run this from VS2013, probably this will run the server on a port different to 80

```
http:/localhost:PORT/boo/foo
```